Former Diplomats with Running Statute of Limitation and Persona Non Grata Status when entering a Country
Let's assume the small country of Ruritania has a diplomat, Alice. While being delegated to Germany, she makes some rather bad remarks about the holocaust and is only shielded from being prosecuted for denial of the Holocaust because she's a diplomat. However, she gets declared a Persona Non Grata and promptly recalled and fired from her cushiony governmental job.
Some months later, Alice wants to attend an exposition held in Hamburg in a purely personal capacity.
So to reiterate: She is neither part of the diplomatic corps, nor has the statute of limitations expired, nor is she removed from the list of unwanted persons - but that only relates to diplomats iirc.
What would be the legal situation as she arrives at the Hamburg Airport and faces customs? Denial of entry or immediate arrest for her prior violations of § 130 & § 189 StGB?

Is Ruritania a member of the European Union or the European Economic Area, or is it Switzerland?

@phoog Ruritania is an unaffiliated nation state on the former border between east and west block, repositioning as needed to border both. It also is starnch neutral and refuses to buy weapons from outside nations, and to sell any to other nations, claiming them more neutral than the swiss.

Another relevant question: why is she presenting herself to German immigration officers?  If she is en route to a diplomatic mission in another country in the Schengen area they may be required by the Schengen Borders Code to allow her to transit; I don't know what their obligations might be under the Vienna Convention, but there probably are some.

@phoog Alice no longer works for Ruritanias diplomatic corps and is on a trip to go to Hamburg Messehallen, so she has to present herself at the entry for the international flight from Ruritania.  She has no diplomatic station anywhere anymore, and the trip is unrelated to diplomatic missions.

She can be denied entry, she cannot be arrested
Assuming that the offence was carried out in the course of her diplomatic duties and not under one of the exemptions in Article 31.1, then her immunity by virtue of Article 39.2 continues forever. That means she cannot be arrested or prosecuted for them. Note that this is for any offence, including murder.
She can, under s 15 of the Act on the Residence, Economic Activity and Integration of Foreigners in the Federal Territory be refused entry if “there is a public interest in expelling the foreigner”.

See §39(2) Vienna Convention on Diplomatic Relations, which the Federal Republic of Germany has ratified:

When the functions of a person enjoying privileges and immunities have
come to an end, such privileges and immunities shall normally cease at
the moment when he leaves the country, or on expiry of a reasonable
period in which to do so, but shall subsist until that time, even in
case of armed conflict. However, with respect to acts performed by
such a person in the exercise of his functions as a member of the
mission, immunity shall continue to subsist.

The answer to your question depends on if the remarks where made as part of her diplomatic role, which seems like a valid assumption.

That's not the point: PNG is pretty much a "get out now, you stop being a diplomat in 48 hours" and not a privilege. It's more of a punishment, and you do not answer the actual question: Is that entry still valid to deny entry, allow arrest or something else?

You do not provide sufficient information in your hypothetical scenario. Assuming they did the remarks in their official capacity, they can't be arrested. Since they are not a diplomat anymore, "persona non grata"  is not relevant and it doesn't necessarily mean they have to leave the country anyway if the sending state terminates their function  with the diplomatic mission. Normal visa consideration apply and of course they can be denied visa if they need one.

@Trish PNG is absolutely not a punishment.  It is a mechanism to ensure that (or more accurately a consequence of the principle that) diplomats are only present with the agreement of the receiving state.  But the real question here is about the nature and scope of personal immunity with respect to criminal acts, and as this answer points out, the scope depends on the capacity in which the criminal act allegedly occurred.

She can be refused future entry if Germany wishes to do so.  If they wanted to prevent her entering Germany, they would put also have to put her on alert on the Schengen Information System so she could not enter Germany through another Schengen country.
Unless Ruritania had waived diplomatic immunity, it would be inappropriate for Germany to charge Alice in Germany or seek her arrest in a third country for her actions in Germany while a diplomat, though they might reasonably deport her if they found her in Germany.

"they might reasonably deport her if they found her in Germany": under international law, yes, but under German law they would need a legal basis for the deportation, and it could not be as a punishment for criminal violation of §§ 130 and 189.  Under German law they would need some statutory basis for deporting her, perhaps because of her presence in Germany being a threat to public safety or public policy (which would be the only valid reasons if Ruritania were a member of the EU,or EEA, or if it is Switzerland).
